# What is the domain of the function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

[image]

I think the subset D is 1/n where n is an element of natural numbers.

Can someone help me with this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That subset $D$ *almost* works, except you do not have anything that corresponds to $0$ which is in the range of $f$. Therefore you could add a particular irrational number to $D$. (A previous version of this answer said you could add zero, but that was a mistake.)

So you can write the answer as

$$D=\{y: y=\pi \lor y=\frac 1n \text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$$

(I prefer to avoid $\Bbb N$ since some authors take it to include zero and others to exclude zero.)

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to map to the full range of $f$, which includes $0$. 
Hence you could take something like $D=\{\,\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}\cup\{\sqrt 2\}$